# Make newly created or uploaded (via ftp) files belongs to a group by default

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, apache-http-server, ftp

Each time you create a file or upload it via FTP, considering your user is "myuser", it's chwon would be "myuser" for user and "myuser" for group. So you have to manually execute `chown` command to change the group ownership to lets say apache.

I'm constantly uploading project files to my development server, and I have to manually `chown` those files to the a group that **apache** and **myuser** belongs to, so that they can be executed.

Is there a way to make this files I upload or create automatically belong to an specific group (lets say "www-data"), so that I dont have to chown em manually? If so, guide me please as I am no expert in linux, I'm like intermediate.

PS: Using CentOS 6.5

Comment: See ["What's the best way of handling permissions for apache2's user www-data in /var/www?"](http://serverfault.com/q/6895/4276)

Comment: if you set SetGID on a folder, all objects created within it take on the group of the parent folder. I set SetGID on my samba folders, so that users can create files, and other users can access them by default, but without write privilege. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/understand-the-setuid-and-setgid-permissions-to-improve-security/

Comment: @FrankThomas I believe your comment is what I'm looking for, would you mind posting it as an answer (and if possible an example) so I can mark it as the selected answer?]

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the `usermod` command that apply. With and without `-a` which means add or append. Without `-a` the users other groups will be removed, with `-a` the new group is added to existing groups.

I actually read ["How do I change a user's primary group?"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-change-a-user%27s-primary-group-383193/) right before I do it, because it's not a function you deal with everyday.

Comment: Don't worry, that's why the web site is collaborative. Some info is better than no info in my opinion.